# Where does record_info/2 export?

Tags: erlang

I often saw:

```
record_info(fields, Record) -> [Field]

record_info(size, Record) -> Size
```

But I did't find the api in module "erlang" http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html

Why?

Answer (score 4):

Erlang has a lot of documentation, so sometimes you don't find what you are looking for so fast.
Take a look at this link: http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/records.html

It says, that the function `record_info` is added on every module that uses records at compile time.

Comment: To each module using records, a pseudo function is added during compilation to obtain information about records: